# How do I map one to many relationship on a JSP page and store them while submitting the page?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

Suppose, I have one class `Student` and another one is `Books`. The `Student` class having one to many relationship with `Books`.

Now, I want to take the the data from user like student name, city etc and add the `Books` details like book name, author, price etc. on the same page. User can add multiple `Books` details(obviously). And then, I want to submit the page with all the nested object(books) data filled along with parent. How can I do that?

You can take any other example instead of student and books as long as the requirement is satisfied.

This is my JSP file:

```
// here student is a parent object and book is a child object having name,author etc details.

<body>
  ${company} form
  <form:form commandName="student" action="../homeController/getDetails"
      id="studentForm">
    Name: 
    <form:input path="name" id="name" />
    City:
    <form:input path="city" id="city" />
    <form:input path="books.bookName" id="bookname"/>
    <form:input path="books.bookAuthor" id="bookauthor"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" style="width: 50px; height: 20px;"
        value="Submit">Submit</button>
  </form:form>
</body>
```

If you can provide me a good link, that would also be a great help.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? If so, add the code to the question. The question is too broad too. For example are you using any ORM framework like JPA/Hibernate?

Comment: yes i am using hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write javascript for it but I will give you the idea to do so.

In your JSP have a form lets say `name=StudentDataForm`. In that form you do something like -

```
<form name="StudentDataForm" action="/submitStudentData.htm" method="post">
<div id="student1">
Name : <input type="text" id="studentname1" name="studentname" >
City : <input type="text" id="studentcity1" name="city" >
<div id="books>
Books : <input type="text" id="student1book1" name="bookstudent1" >
Books : <input type="text" id="student1book2" name="bookstudent1" >
</div>
</div>
<div id="student2">
Name : <input type="text" id="studentname2" name="studentname" >
City : <input type="text" id="studentcity2" name="city" >
<div id="books>
Books : <input type="text" id="student2book1" name="bookstudent2" >
Books : <input type="text" id="student2book2" name="bookstudent2" >
Books : <input type="text" id="student2book3" name="bookstudent2" >
Books : <input type="text" id="student2book4" name="bookstudent2" >
</div>
</div>
</>
</form>
```

Concept is keep the `name` same for same entities like all books for a student have `name = bookstudent2`. Then on your controller or servlet you can get the data as

```
String[] books = request.getParameterValues("bookstudent2");
```

By what you are doing getting the `command object` you can only show it on the UI (By iterating on the Student or Books in the command object using their correct path). But you cannot do it the other way around meaning you cannot manipulate data on UI and send it via command Object.

> How can i do that without using javascript. How can i bind child object's data with the parent object while submitting the form?

If you have fixed number of student and fixed number of books you can do what you desire. take a look at [this link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/). But if you want to add Student and Books dynamically as far as my understanding goes you have to use the way I have described above.

Comment: How can i do that without using javascript. How can i bind child object's data with the parent object while submitting the form?

Comment: For adding data dynamically no. Refer to the updated answer and the link in it.