# Spring, hibernate jsp: binding ManyToMany relationship to form

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I am trying to bind a ManyToMany relationship to JSP but apparently that is not so easy.

```
@Entity
public Course {
    Set<Student> students;
}

@Entity
public Student {
    Set<Course> courses;
}
```

Now as per:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/

[How do I map one to many relationship on a JSP page and store them while submitting the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960504/how-do-i-map-one-to-many-relationship-on-a-jsp-page-and-store-them-while-submitt)

[spring input path for list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838021/spring-input-path-for-list)

[Spring 3 MVC: one-to-many within a dynamic form (add/remove on create/update)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671640/spring-3-mvc-one-to-many-within-a-dynamic-form-add-remove-on-create-update)

http://www.dineshonjava.com/2013/08/spring-crud-example-using-many-to-one.html#.VunkNeIrKM8

To bind JSP children elements ie students we need to use indexing such as:

        
        
        
        
    
https://jsfiddle.net/2wjw708s/

(I have to use jsfiddle as the jsp segment is not rendered by this website.)

This will not work for set.However, for many to many relationship I need to use set instead of list otherwise it gives some exception.

So now I am in a sticky situaion - I can't use list for manytomany relationship and I can't bind without list.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Why not try to use DTO objects. This way you don't pollute JSP pages with Entities and you get the benefit to transform your objects into whatever display-friendly format.

Comment: I can do that and I was thinking about that too. But I need to convert one bean to another (copying fields) and the children element from set to list.

Comment: This should be possible. All you have to do is write a transformer to convert entity to DTO for each type of entity. For example you can use [conversion services](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/ConversionService.html) provided by Spring or [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/deepmapping.html) lib or [Apache Beanutils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html) to do that